# 外部JSのfunction Window.hogeが呼べないのは何故ですか？

Tags: javascript, swift, xcode, xcode6, webview

SwiftでWebViewを使いガワネイティブのアプリを開発しています。
UIViewControllerから値を外部JSで宣言している関数へ値を送れません。
何故でしょうか？

以下コードで、window.a()は呼び出せますが、window.hoge()が呼び出せません。
index.htmlにてwindow.hoge()を呼び出すトンネルを作るしかないのでしょうか？

HogeViewController.swift(抜粋)

```
let webView: UIWebView = UIWebView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView.frame = view.bounds
    webView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(webView)

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("html/index", ofType: "html")!
    let url = NSURL(string: path)!
    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url,
        cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60.0)
    webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)

    println("url : " + path)

}

//略
//何らかのイベントにより、onLoad後、WebViewに送信
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("window.a('" + "hoge" + "')")
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("window.Hoge('" + "hoge" + "')")
```

HTMLとJSファイル

index.html(部)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/hoge.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function a(arg){
    window.log(arg.length);
}

</script>
```

hoge.js

```
window.hoge = function(binay){
    window.log("recodedMovie");

    return true
}

window.log = function(str){
    console.log(new Date() + " : " + str);

    // ログ送信に使用する機能を実装
    var strBase64 = encodeURIComponent(str)
    var URL = "nativehoge://log/"

    // ログをネイティブに送信
    var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", URL + strBase64);
    document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    iframe = null;

};
```

以上です。
宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

ここですが、

> webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("window.Hoge('" + "hoge" + "')")

`window.hoge('" + "hoge" + "')` の間違いではないでしょうか？

Comment: 遅くなりましたが、回答ありがとうございました。
本件解決しました。
まず、ppmさんの仰るとおりtypoをしていました。

また、

> onLoad後、WebViewに送信

と記載しましたが実際はonload完了していなかったためでした。